# Split string column on Dataset<Row> and get new column on Dataset<Row>

Tags: java, sql, apache-spark, dataset, apache-spark-sql

I am working on Spark SQL with Spark(2.0) and using Java API for reading CSV.

In CSV file there is a double quotes, / separated Column. Ex: `"Express Air,Delivery Truck"`

Code for reading CSV and returning Dataset:

```
Dataset<Row> df = spark.read()
                .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
                .option("inferSchema", "true")
                .option("header", "true")
                .load(filename)
```

Result:

```
+-----+-----------------------+--------------------------+
|Year |       State           |                Ship Mode |...
+-----+-----------------------+--------------------------+
|2012 |New York/California    |Express Air/Delivery Truck|...
|2013 |Nevada/Texas           |Delivery Truck            |...
|2014 |North Carolina/Kentucky|Regular Air/Delivery Truck|...
+-----+-----------------------+--------------------------+
```

But, I want to split `State` and `Shop Mode` to `Mode` Column and return as a Dataset and want it to keep their order. ex) {New York,Express Air}  {California,Delivery Truck}

```
+-----+--------------------------+
|Year |      Mode                |   
+-----+--------------------------+
|2012 |New York,Express Air      |
|2012 |California,Delivery Truck |
|2013 |Nevada,Delivery Truck     |
|2013 |Texas,Delivery Truck      |
|2014 |North Carolina,Regular Air|
|2014 |Kentucky,Delivery Truck   |
+-----+--------------------------+
```

Is there any way I can do this using Java Spark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Spark SQL approach:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("tab")

val q = """
with m as (
  select year, explode(split(State, "/")) as State, row_number() over(order by year) as rn from tab
), s as (
  select year, explode(split(`Ship Mode`, "/")) as Mode, row_number() over(order by year) as rn from tab
)
select m.year, m.State, s.Mode
from m
join s
  on m.year = s.year and m.rn = s.rn
"""

spark.sql(q).show
```

Result:

```
scala> spark.sql(q).show
+----+--------------+--------------+
|year|         State|          Mode|
+----+--------------+--------------+
|2012|      New York|   Express Air|
|2012|    California|Delivery Truck|
|2013|        Nevada|Delivery Truck|
|2014|North Carolina|Delivery Truck|
+----+--------------+--------------+
```

you can easily concatente columns if you need:

```
val q = """
with m as (
  select year, explode(split(State, "/")) as State, row_number() over(order by year) as rn from tab
), s as (
  select year, explode(split(`Ship Mode`, "/")) as Mode, row_number() over(order by year) as rn from tab
)
select m.year, concat(m.State, ',', s.Mode) as Mode
from m
join s
  on m.year = s.year and m.rn = s.rn
"""
```

Result:

```
scala> spark.sql(q).show(false)
+----+-----------------------------+
|year|Mode                         |
+----+-----------------------------+
|2012|New York,Express Air         |
|2012|California,Delivery Truck    |
|2013|Nevada,Delivery Truck        |
|2014|North Carolina,Delivery Truck|
+----+-----------------------------+
```

PS i've used Scala, but it should be pretty much the same for Java...

Comment: How can i solve when there are another additional column? ( Type columns added. ex){2012, New York/California, Express Air/Delivery Truck, a/b }   Expected result :  {New York,Express Air,a} {California,Delivery Truck,b}

Comment: @yong, you would use the same technique- add one more table in the “with” clause, join with this new table and concatenate new column... Currently i’m On my phone, so I can’t test it

Comment: Thanks for comment but i have one more question. In join query, how can i make it to multiple join? ex) add one more table 'k' . How do my query at from and join part?

Comment: @yong, “from m join s on ... join k on m.year = k.year and m.rn = k.rn”

Answer (score 0):

yes it's doable using several step.

**Step 1** ds1 <- year | concat (state 1st part , 1st part of mode)

**Step 2** ds2 <- year |concat ( state 2nd part , 2nd part of mode )

**Step 3** ds3 <- ds1 union all ds2 order by year

Should do the job